# angular ui-bootstrap typeahead callback on selectMatch?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using the angular ui-bootstrap typeahead and I would want to use it as a way to pick up many choices, so I'd need to get the selected value when selectMatch method is launched but I can't find how to do that in my controller

```
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
<pre>Model: {{selected| json}}</pre>
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue">
```

If I watch the selected value, I got the change every time a key is pressed...

```
scope.$watch('selected', function(newValue, oldValue) {... });
```

I got that the method selectMatch is the one which is called when the user press enter or click on the list but I don't know how to have a callback on that...

Thanks !

Answer (score 256, accepted):

There is better way of doing this now. [A new callback method has been added](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

In controller file add the following:

```
 $scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label) {
    $scope.$item = $item;
    $scope.$model = $model;
    $scope.$label = $label;
};
```

In view add the following:

```
 <input type="text"
        ng-model="selected"
        typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue"
        typeahead-editable="false"
        typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)"/>
```

See the [typeahead spec](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/91ac17c9ed691a99647b66b3f464e3585398be19/src/typeahead/test/typeahead.spec.js#L372) for more information (search for onSelect).

Check out if the following URLs helps
http://www.techguides.in/how-to-create-autocomplete-using-angularjs-ui/

http://www.techguides.in/how-to-customize-autocomplete-to-display-multiple-columns-using-angularjs-ui-2/

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm.  This should probably be officially documented at the reference page under the Typeahead heading:  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Does anybody have an idea what the $item $model $label objects actually are in that callback typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item, $model, $label)'?

Comment: @Matt,  is there anyway we can do postback in using $http with onSelect event?

Comment: @AardVark71 $item $model $label these three properties are as below respectively. If you are binding JSON array of objects having more than one property, then you will get selected item in $item with all the properties. $model is inbuilt angular model used which will store selected item.value and $lable will give you the value displayed in the text box after selection. So in short many a time, $label will be equal to $model. Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Thanks @Matt -- I tried to use this answer couldn't get the `onSelect` callback to work. Here is [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365371/updating-the-model-from-a-typeahead-on-select) in case you happen to know the answer.

Comment: removed the earlier comments as the links were not working

Can you please check these link if it helps 

http://www.techguides.in/how-to-create-autocomplete-using-angularjs-ui/

and 

http://www.techguides.in/how-to-customize-autocomplete-to-display-multiple-columns-using-angularjs-ui-2/

Comment: @AardVark71 It is easier to explain if the expression is like:

`state.id as state.name for state in states`.

In that case `$item` is `state`, $model is `state.id`, and `$label` is `state.name`

Answer (score 10):

Edit: this method is not the best one now. It's better to use onSelect callback like explained in the answer above this one.

I found how how do to do what I wanted. I did see that there is a typeahead-editable attribute and if it's set to false then the selected value change only when a value from the model is selected. And so the $watch is working fine to check when a new value is selected.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-editable="false">

link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
    scope.$watch('selected', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue)
          console.log(oldValue+"->"+newValue);
     });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*Following should be your HTML*

```
 <input id="title" type="text"  ng-model="title"  typeahead="data.enquiry_title for data in titleData | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item, $model, $label)' />
```

just add **typeahead-on-select** in input tag with the callback function.

*Following would go inside controller*

```
$scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label) {
            console.log($item);
            if($item.tid)
                $scope.activeTitleId = $item.tid
        };
```

inside $item you'll get the whole object which you have passed in the main array of suggestion list

Answer (score 0):

try the following before validation

```
 modelCtrl.$setValidity('editable', true);
```