# Updating the model from a typeahead-on-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Consider the following in the body of my `html` file:

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="name as entry.name for entry in entries | filter:{name: $viewValue} | limitTo:8" 
                 typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item, $model, $label)'
                 class="form-control">

{{selection_made}}
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

where `entries` are populated somewhere else. And then this in the controller:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        ...
        $scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label) {
                $scope.$selection_made = $item;
        };
...
});
```

I have the autocomplete working, but the selection callback doesn't seem to work well. 
I was expecting `{{selection_made}}` to display whatever is selected, but instead the literal text `{{selection_made}}` gets rendered. Why? What am I missing?

Note: I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17994624/283296) for reference.

Comment: Thanks @Satpal, yes I tried that without luck (I get the exact same thing)

Comment: If you put a debugger above the $scope.selection_made = $item; line, and you inspect the item, model, and label. Do they contain the information that you expect?

Comment: @KreepN Yes, I just checked and it does. Except model, which seems to be "undefined".

Comment: Follow-Up: If you add $scope.$apply(); after your assignment line, do you still see the string "{{selection_made}}"? (Make sure it's lower-case, as I pasted incorrectly a second ago).

Comment: Thanks a lot @KreepN .... You pointed me in the right direction with the debugger. The problem was that I was doing `$scope.$selection_made = $item` (I used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17994624/283296)). Changing things to `$scope.selection_made = $item` fixed everything. Thanks

Comment: Lol, now that you point that out, it's obvious. I totally looked past that. Silly me. Glad you got it.

Comment: @KreepN I presume that the answer I linked to also has it wrong then?

Comment: Angular UI actually expects that syntax: $scope.$[variablename]. In your case, if you changed {{selection_made}} to {{$selection_made}}, and left your onSelect code the way you have it in your question, it would have worked.